# Drawing a subset of a plane, which contains two inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, graphing-functions, plane-geometry

I have a question regarding graph sketching:

For example I have the following:

Let $S_1 = \{(x,y) : (x − 1)^2 + (y − 1)^2 < 1\}$ be a subset of the plane $P = \{(x,y) : x,y \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Drawing this would be trivial since, it has the center of $(1,1)$ and radius of $r = 1$.

Now if I have something like $A = \{(x, y) : |x| \leq 1, |y − 1| \leq 1\}$.

We have two inequalities $ |x| \leq 1$ and $|y − 1| \leq 1$, when sketching the graph should I jsut draw the intersection between them (which leads to have small rectangle)? or I should I consider them as two separate sets (which result to have large areas).
I'm not sure since the set takes two inequalities and no value would be repeated.

Approach one:

[image]

Approach Two:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression $|x|\leqslant1,|y-1|\leqslant1$ actually means $|x|\leqslant1\color{red}{\text{ and }}|y-1|\leqslant1$. So, it's the intersection of the sets $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid|x|\leqslant1\}$ and $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid|y-1|\leqslant1\}$, which turns out to be a square.

Besides, I don't see functions here.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the functions to inequalities, or 'equation' is better?

Comment: Yes, inequalities is better.

Comment: if I have $\{ (x,y): -1 < x < 2 \}$, would that be just a line on the X-Achse ? or all the values of y also where x between -1 and 2?, I think since we have y also in the definition we should also include the values of y, right? and if not we don't include it

Comment: All points of the form $(x,y)$, with $-1<x<2$, belong to that set. It's a sort of infinite rectangle.